# How to get Spinner item as TextView

Tags: android, spinner

I have a Spinner where user can choose their topping for the ordered drink. I wanted to show drink name, selected topping and also price in the Cart.

How do i cast the item selected from Spinner to TextView (cart_item_topping) from xml?

Thank you.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cart_item_name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Drink 01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cart_item_topping"  //this will be retrived from Spinner
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:text="Topping 01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cart_item_price"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:text="100.00"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Holder class

```
class CartViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
    ,View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {

public TextView txt_cart_name, txt_price;
public ImageView img_cart_count;

private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public void setTxt_cart_name(TextView txt_cart_name) {
    this.txt_cart_name = txt_cart_name;
}

public CartViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    txt_cart_name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_name);
    txt_price = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_price);
    img_cart_count = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_count);
    //code for selected topping from spinner

    itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
}
```

Comment: please add the code you have so far (following https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you out.

Comment: you want to put all of that in a spinner? you need an adapter

Comment: @DroiDev, i have a spinner and user will need to choose one item from spinner. I wanted to display the selected item from spinner in Cart, which is the cart_item_topping, can refer to my codes. How can i retrieve the selected item and cast it to TextView?

Comment: @emersso yup already attached my code as well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GOTCHA. Well, when you select from the spinner, you need to get that text. then, when you click on view cart, you need to do the following...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CheckOut.class);
intent.putExtra("toppings", toppings);
startActivity(intent);
```

then you need to get it in the new activity.

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("toppings");
```

What I would do is use a model.

Example:

toppingsID,
toppingsName,
toppingsPrice.

Create getters for this.

From there, you fill in the spinner with the getter, and you pass in the ID of the toppings so you can iterate through the list of toppings and display it.

Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

when you select item then recycleradapter set into recyclerview and also
set spinner onitemselectedlistener see this code hear...

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        recyclerview.setAdapter(your adapter with data id);
        //hear data id set into cunstouctor like cursor and etc.
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }

});
```